# Java - creating separate thread for sending objects over the Internet

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, event-handling, connection

I am writing Battleships game in Java for Event-Driven Programming on my studies. The game is supposed to be a network game and i am going to make client and server in one application.

This is an image representing structure of my application:
[class diagram http://dl.dropbox.com/u/41993645/mvc.jpeg](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/41993645/mvc.jpeg)

To get to the point - i want to write Server class that will run as separate thread and are responsible for remote View - Controller communication. So, the Server class will be responsible for:

- Reading objects from socket in infinite loop and if any arrives,
  putting them in the BlockingQueue for the Controller.
- Providing method like 'sendActionEventToView()' which will allow Controller to pass object the other way - from Controller to remote View.

Unfortunately, when running the Server thread, whole application stops responding. If anybody would tell me what am i doing wrong, i would be very grateful. This is in my opinion the problematic part of Server code:

```
/** Main Server method - responsible for reading objects
 *  and putting them in the queue if any arrived */
public void run() {
  GameEvent event;
  while(true) {
    try {
      event = (GameEvent)objectStream.readObject();
      if(event != null) eventQueue.put(event);
    } catch(ClassNotFoundException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } catch(IOException e1) {
      e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch(InterruptedException e2) {
      e2.printStackTrace(); 
    }
  }
}
```

I think thread hangs on 'readingObject()' - how can i force it to give processor time to another threads if there are not any objects in the stream?

Rest of Server: https://github.com/mc-suchecki/Battleships/blob/master/controller/Server.java
Rest of the app: https://github.com/mc-suchecki/Battleships

Thank you very much in advance, if anything is unclear, please comment. And sorry for my English.

Comment: You are going to have to post some concise code examples before most will answer.  I suggest that you add more `println` debugging or use a debugger to figure out your issue.

Comment: Thanks, i've posted the problematic code. I've tried debugging, but my knowledge allowed me just to find the problem, but unfortunately not to solve it.

Comment: Are you starting one thread per client or are you reading from one client connection at a time?

Comment: Right, I've should wrote it. The game is supposed to be a p2p - in the beginning the player selects whether he want to host the game or connect to another server. Every server allows only one client. See createServer() and connectToServer() code: https://github.com/mc-suchecki/Battleships/blob/master/view/View.java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just found the problem - it was in the constructor:

```
/** Server class constructor */
public Server(BlockingQueue<GameEvent> queue) {
  eventQueue = queue;
  try {
    serverSocket = new ServerSocket(Constants.PORT_NUMBER);
    socket = serverSocket.accept();  
    inputStream = socket.getInputStream();  
    objectStream = new ObjectInputStream(inputStream);  
  } catch(IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }  
  Thread thread = new Thread(this);
  thread.start();
}
```

Line with `socket = serverSocket.accept()` hanged the application *before* separate thread was created. I don't know why, but I've looked for a problem in `run()` method, and that was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Normal java streams are *blocking*.  this means that you generally want to use 2 threads per socket connection (assuming bi-directional communication).  one thread is devoted to *each stream* (input/output) for *each socket connection*.

Comment: OK, I know - I have only tried to do one-way communication already. To be precise - there will be only one socket in the server and one socket in the client - application is supposed to be p2p.

Answer (score 0):

If you are really using multiple threads then when one thread is blocked then other threads are going to run.  There is no need to "force" the processor to give time to other threads.

Looking at your code your view calls the Controller's run method directly instead of giving it to another thread to run:
https://github.com/mc-suchecki/Battleships/blob/75e6cf69d081c05845f4171bf42ce096ed5247a7/view/View.java#L48 which would cause the `Controller's` code to be run in the same thread that called `createServer`.

In your gist you are already submitting your `Controller` to a new thread in the `Controller's` constructor (https://gist.github.com/2835863#L46).  I'd assume you can just remove the call to "controller.run()" in your view.

Comment: Thank you, that's right that controller.run() is unnecessary, but the problem still exist.

Answer (score 0):

If your code public void run(); is started using Thread's start method, the readObject can block only that thread.

Comment: I've thought the same when I was writing Server code, but still the application hangs for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your *run* method has a thread all to itself.  I suspect you're doing to much with one thread; all your threads are really one thread and they're all waiting on the socket.  And when they (singular) read something they just go back and wait on the socket again.

Use your IDE to make sure you have all the threads you need.  Use your debugger.  Pause the program when it hangs and check all the threads.  Make sure you have at least two.  (If you don't, that's the problem.)  *One* thread *should* be hanging on the socket read.  Check where the others, if they exist, are hanging and fix the code so they don't.